# Почему delete не удаляет свойство?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

```
let product_params;
product_params = await BlackProduct.findOne({id: 1})
.then(res => (res))

if (!product_params){
   return null
   // Если документ не найден, то заканчиваю выполнение функции
}
else{
   delete product_params._id;
}

console.log(product_params)
```

Но когда вывожу в консоль

```
console.log(product_params)
```

то все равно свойство _id присутствует.

```
// delete product_params._id === true
```

Comment: Я понимаю, что в опциях могу указать нужные мне поля для возврата из базы. Но мне интересно почему же не удаляется свойство

Comment: А в каком месте вы выводите `console.log(product_params)`?  Покажите полный пример кода.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko, дополнил вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Mongoose свойство "id" создается по умолчанию и является виртуальным, возвращающим значение "_id".
Если вы хотите отключить автоматическое создание свойства "id", вы можете сделать это при определении схемы:

```
var schema = new Schema({ name: String }, { id: false });
```

Так же вы можете трансформировать `product_params` в объект и удалить ключ _id:

```
const data = product_params.toObject();
delete data[_id];
```

Иллюстрирующий пример (по итогам обсуждения в комментах):

```js
class A {
    get _id() {
        return Math.random();
    }
}
const obj = new A();
console.log(obj._id);
delete obj._id;
console.log(obj._id);
delete obj._id;
console.log(obj._id);
```

Comment: а что значит виртуальное свойство? Ведь delete product_params._id === true. Логично что delete смог удалить свойство, раз вернул true.

Comment: всё б/м прописано в https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#id и https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#_id

Comment: Так в вопросе-то удаляется как раз `_id`, а не `id`. И сам вопрос-то на самом деле не о том, **как** удалить `_id`, а **почему** `delete` не дает ожидаемого результата.

Comment: потому что _id - это геттер

Comment: Ну вот у меня сходу воспроизвести не получилось: `let obj = {get a() {return 42}}; console.log(obj.a) /* 42 */; delete obj.a; console.log(obj.a) /* undefined */`. То есть геттер как таковой прекрасно удаляется через `delete`.

Comment: @Yaant https://jsfiddle.net/aq1mez9g/

Comment: Ага, спасибо, у меня было подозрение, что дело в наследовании, но проверить руки не дошли. :)